# Django Rest Framework for function based views

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble getting the JSON for function based views in django. I have the below code. I basically would like the function to return either json or an html page based on the user request.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer,BrowsableAPIRenderer))
def meld_live_orders(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
        current_orders = Meld_Sales.objects.values_list('TicketNo',flat=True).distinct()
        prev_orders = Meld_Order.objects.values_list('TicketNo',flat =True).distinct()

        live_orders = live_order_generator(current_orders,prev_orders)

        return render(request,'live_orders.html',{'live_orders':live_orders})
```

When i go to the url - `http://localhost:8000/live-orders.json`

I'm getting an error which states the below -`meld_live_orders() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'`

Is this because i need to include the serializer class somewhere the same way in CBVs? Doesnt the `@API_VIEW` serialize the response?

i tried including `format = ''` in the function argument. but the problem is that it still renders html when i want it to render json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your code.

Firstly, you need to use [`format_suffix_patterns`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/#format_suffix_patterns) in your urls if you have not defined it. This will allow us to use filename extensions on URLs thereby providing an endpoint for a given media type.

```
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
     ...
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'html']) # allow us to use '.json' and '.html' at the end of the url
```

Secondly. your view does not have a `format` parameter in the definition.

> When using `format_suffix_patterns`, you must make sure to add the
>   `'format'` keyword argument to the corresponding views.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer,BrowsableAPIRenderer))
def meld_live_orders(request, format=None): # add a 'format' parameter
    ...
```

Thirdly, **you need to return a DRF response and not a Django response** which you are returning at the end of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You must have match a `format` parameter in the url pattern, but in the view function there is not an argument named `format`. Change the view definition into:

```
def meld_live_orders(request, format = ""):
```

Comment: I actually tried that .. sorry for skipping it in the question .. it still renders in html when i want it to render a json

Comment: Would you please present your url pattern?

Comment: Well i know, in the last line you have rendered a HTML page as the response, which should be a rest_framework.response.Response object.

Comment: is there a way i could have both? i.e the user gets json data only by including .json after the url?

my url pattern - **url(r'^live-orders$',meld_live_orders,name='live-orders')**

Comment: Please lookup the document carefully. The correct way is to pass data of the serializer to the Response object. For JSONRenderer, the data will be converted into JSON format; for TemplateHTMLRenderer, the data will be pass to the template as a context variable.

Comment: I'm sorry if if i misunderstood .. but i wanted to have both formats and I was of the belief that you'd get both if you give **@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,TemplateHTMLRenderer,BrowsableAPIRenderer))** as a decorator. i'll look it up again :)